# Trouble configuring Play 2 to run with JPA (persistence)

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.0, persistence-unit

The folowing error is being showed when a try to persist data:

```
[PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: update] class or package not found]
In C:\Users\Johann\Desktop\SODET\play-2.1.1\todolist\app\models\Stream.java at line 32.



32                EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("update");
```

This is **Stream.java (a model)**

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import com.restfb.Facebook;

@Entity
public class Stream {
      @Facebook
      @Id
      public String post_id;

      @Facebook
      public String created_time;

      @Facebook
      public String message;

      @Facebook
      public String permalink;

      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s, %s, %s, %s", created_time, message, permalink, post_id);
      }

      public void save(){
          EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("update");
          EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
          entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
          entityManager.persist(this);      
          entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
          entityManager.close();
      }

}
```

The **persistence.xml** file is in the conf/META-INF directory:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="update" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>

        <class>models.Stream</class>
        <class>models.FacebookUser</class>
        <class>models.Comment</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

And this is **Build.scala**

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName         = "todolist"
  val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    "com.restfb" % "restfb" % "1.6.11",
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.25",
    "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.2.1.Final",
    javaCore,
    javaJdbc,
    javaJpa
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    // Add your own project settings here      
  )

}
```

I looked documentation and found nothing about that...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Note**: i don't know a whole lot about Hibernate + persistence. You should be able to obtain an `EntityManager` like this: `EntityManager manager = JPA.em();` in Play. You can then call `manager.persist(this);` etc. This works for me but I have an additional property in my `persistence.xml` : `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>`. Also, probably unrelated to your problem but since you're using MySQL, you should change to dialect to `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect` instead of using the `H2Dialect`.

Answer (score 0):

regard in your application.conf the name is not the same as update : example :

jpa.update=updatePersistenceUnit

I think you don't have this line the application have to match in application.conf and hibernate file

note : the value update in hbm2dll is just for update the DB schema if it changes in model. i think you have to use the defaultPersistentUnit name because in application.conf it maybe like this :

jpa.default=defaultPersistenUnit

then

db.default.driver=your driver
db.defalut.url=your url

Answer (score 0):

Your **persistence.xml** file states the following configuration:

```
<non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
```

---

```
<persistence-unit name="update" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
```

Your **application.conf** must have the following entries

```
# You can expose this datasource via JNDI if needed (Useful for JPA)
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
```

---

```
# JPA configuration
# ~~~~~
# You can declare as many Ebean servers as you want.
# By convention, the default server is named `default`
jpa.default=update
```

Check your mapping or find a crisp explanation [here](http://kerkermeister.net/play-and-hibernate-how-to-get-running-with-your-json-rest-api-2/).